# is there any way to decode result of signature view flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety, dart-pub

```
RepaintBoundary(
  key: genKey,
  child: Signature(
    controller: controller,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
),

Container(
  // decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: <Widget>[
      //SHOW EXPORTED IMAGE IN NEW ROUTE

      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          controller.toPngBytes();
          print(controller.toPngBytes());
          //  List<Point> exportedpoints = controller.points;
          // takePicture();
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              color: Colors.blue),
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                "Done",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
```

I am using signature plugin in flutter and using controller.toPng() to convert it into png file.
and in return am getting
onDrawStart called!
flutter: onDrawEnd called!
flutter: Instance of 'Future<Uint8List?>'
is there any way to decode data in this case ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have solved it , by conve